# select() fails under heavy condition for non_blocking manual timeout connect() calls

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I had to implement a application health check mechanism , I used non blocking socket with `select` although I achieved success

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int connect_tout(char * hostname1, int port, int timeoutval)
{
    char *hostname = hostname1;         /* pointer to name of server */
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;               /* socket address */
    int s, i;

    fd_set fd_r, fd_w;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int flags;

    timeout.tv_sec = timeoutval;
    timeout.tv_usec =  0;

    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname1);
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    /* set the socket fd to non-blocking mode */
    fcntl(s, F_SETFL, (flags = fcntl(s, F_GETFL)) | O_NONBLOCK);

    connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));

    FD_ZERO(&fd_r);
    FD_ZERO(&fd_w);
    FD_SET(s, &fd_r);
    FD_SET(s, &fd_w);

    /*  timeout durring connect() ??  */
    select(s+1, &fd_r, &fd_w, NULL, &timeout);
    if(FD_ISSET(s, &fd_w))
    {
        printf("ALIVE\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Conect TIMEOUT \n");
        close(s);

        return errno;
    }

    i = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    if(i)
    {
        printf("Conect failed errno:%d\n",errno);
        perror("connect:");
        close(s);

        return errno;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connect  passed  and OK \n");
        close(s);

        return 1;
    }

    close(s);
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [host] [port] [timout]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    char *hostname = argv[1];         /* pointer to name of server <IP address>*/

    connect_tout(hostname, atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3])); 

    return 0;
}
```

BUT my problem comes when my code running machine goes under very high fd usage . NOTE: Opening many fds at a time at my system is common behaviour . then this piece fails each time

```
if(FD_ISSET(s, &fd_w))
{
    printf("ALIVE\n");
} 
else
{
    close(s);

    return errno;

    printf("Conect TIMEOUT\n");
}
```

As I said in such environment it fails by saying `TIMEOUT` , I want to know  why `select` is failing by not determining ready discripters so soon and that is each time. Is `FD_ISSET()` may also fall under doubt ?  
P S : This runs well when system is under normal number of fds . Sorry for bad program I just pasted here my sample working code. I will check for errors later

Comment: You're not checking select()'s return value.  Perhaps it is failing and returning -1 for some reason.

Comment: How many fds do you have? The hard upper limit for the *fd value* in `select` is 1023 under Linux. If you need more, you have to switch to `poll` or `epoll` or libevent (you should anyway, regardless).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks for suggestion I tried that even with all proper error checks but when mega-event happens it sur passes all of them

Comment: What is the timeoutval?

Comment: @n.m. FDs goes around 2048 . I think you hit it correctly . I will work around what you said may be it will hunt down my stupidity :)

Comment: @n.m.: The program in this question only opens one descriptor. The error would be in the server, not in this program.

Comment: yes it happens on server. And I have to tune program for that situation

Comment: http://pragmatictips.com/26 applies.

Answer (score 1):

For non-blocking `connect()` usage, you do not call it again after getting writeable notification. Instead, you should check the error status of the socket with `getsockopt()` with the `SO_ERROR` option.

You are not checking the return values of any of your calls, and this makes it impossible for your code to actually determine any failures correctly. Note that you do not check the case if the passed in timeout itself is 0, which would cause `select()` to return immediately with the instantaneous status of the socket. Note that checking for readable notification of the connecting socket is not documented by the socket API.

```
int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
assert(!(s < 0));
int r = fcntl(s, F_SETFL, fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0)|O_NONBLOCK);
assert(r == 0);
r = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
if (r < 0) {
    if (errno == EINPROGRESS) {
        FD_ZERO(&fd_w);
        FD_SET(s, &fd_w);
        r = select(s+1, NULL, &fd_w, NULL, NULL);
        if (r < 0) {
            perror("select");
            abort();
        }
        assert(r == 1);
        assert(FD_ISSET(s, &fd_w));
        int erropt = -1;
        socklen_t errlen = sizeof(erropt);
        r = getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &erropt, &errlen);
        assert(r == 0);
        if (erropt != 0) {
            errno = erropt;
            perror("connect[after select]");
            abort();
        }
        /* connect succeeded asynchronously */
    } else {
        perror("connect[direct call]");
        abort();
    }
} else {
    /* connect succeeded synchronously */
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you very much . I tried it but not so nicely as yours . But may be I got the reason and will workaround as n.m said